# Can aggregate be used on a 3 dimensional array in r

Tags: r

Can aggregate be used on a 3 dimensional array to find the mean of unique days in R?

For example, consider I have a dataset which has three dimensions, say for longitude, latitude, and time, but that one of the times is a duplicate:

```
dtime <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01", tz="UTC"),
             to=as.POSIXct("2012-01-10", tz="UTC"),
             by="day")
dtime[10] <- dtime[9]
a <- array(c(runif(9), runif(9)), c(3,3,10))
```

For an individual lat/lon cell, I can calculate the average for all unique times as:

```
dat2 <- aggregate(a[1,1,], by = list(dtime), mean)
# quick check
dat2b <- dat2[,2]
dat2b[length(dat2b)] == (a[1,1,10]+a[1,1,9])/2
```

but how can I do this for all lat/lon combinations, i.e. apply it to the entire data? Specifically, dat2 for the entire data would have dimensions of

```
> dim(dat2)
[1]  3  3 9
```

instead of the original data which has

```
> dim(a)
[1]  3  3 10
```

as the last two days are duplicates.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an array, `apply` may be the way to go.  This takes in an array and applies some function along a margin that you specify.

To apply the mean across the "z" (time) dimension of your array:

```
apply(a, c(1,3), mean)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3139773 0.4530565 0.4233957
[2,] 0.6579453 0.8921744 0.2593869
[3,] 0.5771248 0.4663132 0.4664523
```

To leave out the tenth (duplicate) matrix in the calculation, just subset:

```
apply(a[,,1:9], c(1,2), mean)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.2917246 0.4719813 0.3774068
[2,] 0.6539847 0.8887012 0.2564051
[3,] 0.5806970 0.4856463 0.4886335
```

As a check, note that the output of applying `mean` to the elements in the first row, first column corresponds to the the appropriate element in the matrix:

```
mean(a[1,1,1:9])
[1] 0.2917246
```

If instead of ignoring the tenth matrix, you wanted to calculate the mean of the 9th and 10th matrices and then calculate the mean across the 9 dimensions, you could use `apply` twice, together with `abind`:

```
library abind
apply(abind(a[,,1:8], apply(a[,,9:10], c(1,2), mean)), c(1,2), mean)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3139773 0.4530565 0.4233957
[2,] 0.6579453 0.8921744 0.2593869
[3,] 0.5771248 0.4663132 0.4664523
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
 a <- array(c(runif(9), runif(9)), c(3,3,10))
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the duplicated time may not always be in the 9th or tenth entry. My actual data is much larger, with numerous duplicated times within

Answer (score 0):

I propose a different approach using `reshape2` functionality `melt` and `acast`. I think this is because I am programmed to think in terms of long format data where you would have a data frame with variables Lon, Lat, Time and Value, making lots of other manipulation easier. To that end...

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

out = apply(a,3, function(x){
  d = melt(x)
  colnames(d) = c("Lat","Lon","Value")
  as.data.frame(d)
} )

df = do.call(rbind,out)
df$time = rep(dtime,each = 9)
```

gives me a 2 dimensional data frame containing the same information as your 3 dimensional array. I wasn't sure if your rows or columns were Lat so I picked one, obviously you know the answer to this so choose accordingly.

Aggregation is then no problem since we have nice format

```
res = aggregate(Value~Lat + Lon + time, data = df, mean)
```

Check your case of the first Lon,Lat pair being correct: (optional `dplyr` use here, can obviously get the subset using `[`)

```
res %>% filter(Lat == 1, Lon == 1) %>% select(Value) == dat2[,2]
```

If you really want your final result to be a 3 dimensional array of (3,3,9) then you can use `acast`

```
acast(res,Lat~Lon~time)
```